# How do I change the annotation colour for a certain changeset

Tags: visual-studio-2017, plasticscm

I am using the annotation feature of the Visual Studio 2017 plug in. The colour scheme seems to be based on the age of the change in a gradient type of style. Is there way to assign a colour to a certain change set? If a number of changes have been made fairly close together, it makes it hard to see which lines belong to which changeset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the color can only be changed based on the author or date. Please check attached screenshot.

[image]